# unity 2020.3 как изменить текст из скрипта привязанного к нему?

Tags: unity3d

Вот код скрипта

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ScoreInt = 0;
    public void ScoreChange(int delta)
    {
        ScoreInt += delta;
        this.text = ScoreInt;
    }

}
```

[image: Скрипт привязан к тексту Score]

Скрипт привязан к тексту Score

Как поменять текст ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ScoreInt = 0;
    public Text ScoreText;
    public void Start()
    {
        ScoreText = GetComponent<Text>(); // получаем компонент Text на текущем объекте
    }
    public void ScoreChange(int delta)
    {
        ScoreInt += delta;
        ScoreText.text = ScoreInt.ToString();
    }
}
```

На текущем объекте получает текст и изменяет его в методе "ScoreChange".